# Как отловить зажатие клавиши Alt в событии MouseDown

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется DataGrid (WinForms), в нем выводится список сущностей. При выборе сущности, в событии

```
viewPoints_FocusedRowObjectChanged(object sender, FocusedRowObjectChangedEventArgs e)
```

поджигаются другие события, производящие некие действия. Необходимо блокировать поджиг этих других событий при условии, что сущность была не просто выбрана, а щелкнута с зажатой клавишей Alt (это означает начало перетаскивания, DragAndDrop).

Событие MouseDown срабатывает раньше события выбора сущности, но имеет параметр MouseEventArgs e, в котором я не нашел ничего, что позволило бы проанализировать зажатую при щелчке клавишу Alt.

Событие DragEnter имеет параметр DragEventArgs e, в котором есть e.KeyState (битовая маска, в том числе и про Alt), но это событие срабатывает позже события выбора строки Grid-а, когда нежелательные по Alt'у действия уже произведены.

Радикальным образом менять архитектуру проекта не представляется возможным. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные пути решения!

Comment: Завести глобальную переменную, хранящую состояние клавиши alt, менять ее значение при поступлении событий от клавиатуры, и в MouseDown анализировать эту переменную

Comment: Герман Борисов, спасибо! Ларчик действительно просто открывался. Принял ваше решение, хотя позже были предложены и иные верные решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете свойство `KeyCode?` и при событии onkeydown записываете текущию клавишу, а в onkeyup задаете этому свойству null. А в mousedown проверяете это свойство. Свойство должно иметь тип, на конце которого должен быть знак вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Ф-ция IsKeyDown [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown)

```
  if ( Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) ||
       Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt)) {
   }
```

Либо getkeystates [msdn](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.getkeystates)

И есть Состояние Modifiers
[msdn](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers)

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) > 0) {
    }
```